# Make classifications with number ranges on Tableau

Tags: class, tableau-api, calculated-field

I Have a deposits parameter. I want to classify population into 3 sections as follows:
high, medium and low

Tried to create a calculated field.This does not work for me in the following way and gives different errors.
Please advise?

```
if 1300<[deposit] then 'high' or
if 1150<[deposit]< 1300 then 'Medium'
 else 'Low' 
 END
 END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have multiple logic comparisons in a single if statement and you need to pay attention to the actual syntax of the `if` statement. Multiple statements can be combined with `elseif` but not by `or`.

So, assuming that `[deposit]` is an integer you could write:

```
if [deposit]>1300 then "high"
elseif [deposit]>1150 then "medium"
else "low"
end
```

Tableau makes the key information on function syntax available just to the right of the function edit box (click the little right triangle if it doesn't appear automatically) so this information isn't hard to find.